# corona android in app purchase restore not working?

Tags: in-app-purchase, coronasdk

In my application in-app purchase and restore work well in Iphone. but android has restore problem.how to get purchased list. restore option not working.how query to get purchased product list.

Comment: did you try to read this http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/monetization/IAP/index.html

Comment: Ya i read that doc.but i can not understand  for they give idea for google play restore.(In the Google Play Marketplace, there is no "restored" state for items. All purchased items will be grouped under the "purchased" state. When you do a restore, you should clear all purchases saved to file/database — except for consumable purchases — and treat the returned restored purchases as normal purchases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play has a store.restore() function.  Unlike iOS which has a transaction.state called "restore", Google Play returns restored items with a transaction.state of "purchase".  You therefore have to check other things like the transaction.date to see how old it is, or check with an online database where you can compare the receipt information with the original receipt info.

In my own code, right before I call store.restore() I set a flag "isRestoring" to true and if my store is Google Play and I'm restoring and I get a "purchase' in my transaction state I know its a restore.

Comment: I tested using test.android.purshaed.but restore not happening.

Comment: Thank you it works fine.i purchased one product and tested it works perfectly.